# How can i change text lable to right?

Tags: html, css

I have this checkbox that display left side  but I want display in right side. How can I do ? 
I use  this style but not work.

[image: Image for describe my problem]

```css
label {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link async="" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/2.0.46/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pretty-checkbox@3.0/dist/pretty-checkbox.min.css">

<div class="pretty p-icon p-curve p-jelly">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="state p-danger">
    <i class="icon mdi mdi-skull">   </i>

    <label style="text-align: right;">hi</label>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you wanting the text to be aligned to the right of side of the page?

Comment: @ Turnip   yes I want   text to be aligned to the right of side of the screen

Comment: Do you need both check box and text aligned to right @JohnKennedy

Comment: yes exactly  i want that @ Ajanyan Pradeep

Comment: I update  my problem  with  image for description

Comment: @AjanyanPradeep Why would giving it an ID solve it? I already suggested to float it

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry Initially when I looked your answer it was only the text moving right side. Didn't  noticed your updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try floating it

```css
div.pretty {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 1em;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link async="" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/2.0.46/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pretty-checkbox@3.0/dist/pretty-checkbox.min.css">
<div class="pretty p-icon p-curve p-jelly">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
  <div class="state p-danger">
    <i class="icon mdi mdi-skull">   </i>
    <label for="chk" style="text-align: right;">hi</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

John with two lines of code you can do that. 
See the changes I made. In HTML I put everything inside a section or div, if you prefer, with class name content. In CSS I wrote two lines of code to change that.  For these things is good to use Flexbox. very easy and less code. Check below.

```css
.content{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}
```

```html
<link async="" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/2.0.46/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pretty-checkbox@3.0/dist/pretty-checkbox.min.css">

<section class='content'>
  <div class=" pretty p-icon p-curve p-jelly">
  
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="state p-danger">
    <i class="icon mdi mdi-skull"></i>
    <label style="text-align: right;">hi</label>
  </div>
  
</div>
</section>
```

Hope this was helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Give id to the div like `chbox`

```
<div class="pretty p-icon p-curve p-jelly" id="chbox">
```

and add the following properties to that id in css

```
#chbox {
  display: block;
    float:right;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

So the code will be:

```css
#chbox {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link async="" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/2.0.46/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pretty-checkbox@3.0/dist/pretty-checkbox.min.css">

<div class="pretty p-icon p-curve p-jelly" id="chbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="state p-danger">
    <i class="icon mdi mdi-skull">   </i>

    <label style="text-align: right;">hi</label>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Same as my suggestion using the div class instead of adding an ID